# Flet, after publishing a static website apps is not works

Tags: flet

I created GUI for my python scripts. I used flet. In the app all work. But when I published app for a static website. In the app all work. But when I published app for a static website.

I used modules

```
import telnetlib
import time
import flet as ft
from pprint import pprint
import re
```

I published app for a static website:

```
flet publish ./scripts.py
flet publish ./scripts_obs.py
```

It stopped working.
web server wrote:
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2023 13:45:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2023 13:45:10] "GET /flutter_service_worker.js?v=2289608434 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2023 13:45:11] "GET /app.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 304 -

All buttons and dropdown work, but body of scripts is not works. Could you help me?